# How can I make sure that data contained in Command is the one needed to make the operation?

Tags: php, cqrs

Example, suppose you have an User entity.

The user has `id`, `username`, `password`.
The id is autogenerated in database.

In an `UpdateUserCommand`, same data should be used.

In an `UpdateUserCommandHandler`, we need the ID to make the query `update users set password ... where id = :id`.

But how can I make sure that I have the data required for building this query? Is the only why a lot of `if (!somedata) trow new MissingSomeDataException()`?

Example:

```
if (!isset($data['id'])) {
   throw new Exception('ID is missing');
if (!isset($data['username'])) {
   throw new Exception('Username is missing');
if (!isset($data['password'])) {
   throw new Exception('password is missing');

$id = (int) $data['id'];
if (!isset($data['id'])) {
   throw new Exception('ID is invalid');

$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery('update Users u ... where u.id = :id)
$this->entityManager->execute($query, $params);
```

Comment: You can make object oriented solution.
For example in Yii Framework they have kind of contract that you mark which fields are required, and command won't run until you provide all what is required. Error message generated automatically

Comment: Yes, it is a most basic validator. I am sure a framework of choice has something a bit more advanced. e.g. [in symfony you can do it with annotations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html)

Comment: @AlexBlex I'm using Symfony. I guess that Form's Validation groups is what I need, because they will handle the constraints, right? So I just get data from the form once it is valid, and I can be confident data is there. But then CommandHandler won't have validation, and someone can misuse them. Maybe I can pass a Form instance into the command handler?

Comment: well, if your `$data` comes from a form, than yes, form validation should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

**Well, technically, yes. Definitely.**

You have to check every input you receive from client, because it may be malformed by a lot of reasons.

Moreover, you will need to check if user with provided ID actually exists, if you are going to do something with it later.

**However**

There are a lot of convenient options to do so.

```
$keys=['id','username','password'];
!array_diff_key(array_flip($keys), $data); // will be TRUE if all keys are there
```

Or you may want to use any ORM or CRUD-framework to make your life (not PHP parser, though) easier - right after you will configure it to check all inputs, it will do it automatically before accessing and querying database, and you will spend time only doing positive business-process level work, not bothering with checking every incoming bit.

Old good book/authors list example on Propel's website will help you to understand what do I mean: [Propel ORM](http://propelorm.org/)